# IF(x="y";"Yes";"No") . How to expand with multiple conditions?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a formula =IF(Functie="Medewerker Verhuur";"Yes";"No")

This works, but now i would like to add the option Medewerker Klantenpunt too.

So, if Functie is Medewerker Verhuur OR Medewerker Klantenpunt, than yes, ELSE No. 
How do i do this? I cannot get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
=IF(OR(Functie="Medewerker Verhuur";Functie="Medewerker Klantenpunt");"Yes";"No")
```

It uses `OR` operator/function which is described [here](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/or-function-fa430d29-4638-404e-8219-9ff07016601f).

Comment: Ah, I recognize my mistake. Thanks. That worked!